# Where to define associations / relations when using Sequelize.js?

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

The official documentation only deals with sample code which defines two separate models followed by association / relation code [as follows](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/associations/#belongsto).

```
var User = this.sequelize.define('user', {/* attributes */})
  , Company  = this.sequelize.define('company', {/* attributes */});

User.belongsTo(Company); // Will add companyId to user
```

My guesses are

1. Require all of the models and define associations in a separate file, then require that file from, say, `app.js`.
2. In each Model file, require needed models and define associations in `classMethods.associate(models)`.

and I can't really decide which one is a "right" way. I'm using Sequelize-CLI to generate migration files and model files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `console.log`ging `models` parameter in `classMethods.associate(function(models) {})`, I've found out that it actually has all the Model classes.

You can access Model like `models.ModelName` and elaborate those to define associations and relations there.